# Ext.tab.Panel not showing content

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have an app that has a form in form.Panel which when the user presses search it brings up the results in a tab.Panel.That all works fine and the tabs work fine first time around. I have a button that allows the user to return to the form.Panel and enter in different information. Again the user presses search and everything shows up fine however if you change from the initial tab and then try to go back to it nothing is displayed. I have no errors in the console just an empty panel with the tab bar at the end. Anybody know of any reason this could be happening?

List Item Tap Controller:

```
     Ext.define('FirstApp.controller.Details', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
    refs: {
        placesNavView:'placesContainer',


    },
    control: {
        'placesContainer places list':{
            itemtap:function(list,index,target,record){

      var ref = record.get('reference');
     var name = record.get('name');
    console.log(name);
      console.log(ref);

    // Instantiate a "please wait" message
    Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask', message:'Please Wait...'});

       var proxy = {
        type:'ajax',
        url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference='+ref+'&sensor=true&key=',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'result'
        }
    }
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('Details').setProxy(proxy);
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('Details').load();

    console.log(proxy);


             Ext.getCmp('placesContainer').push({
         xtype: 'details',
       title: name
          });

       Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);


            }
        }

    }

  }
  });
```

Update:

```
 Ext.define('FirstApp.view.PlacesContainer',{
 extend:'Ext.NavigationView',

 xtype:'placesContainer',
 id:'placesView',

config:{
    title:'Places',
    iconCls:'organize',
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'places'
        }

    ]
   }
  })
```

Comment: I have added code to original question i can add more code if needs be

Comment: After a few hours i think the problem is with adding an ID to a navigationView. I have added the code above. I was using the ID in the list item tap above

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you hardcoded `id: placesView`, try to use `itemId` instead.

```
xtype:'placesContainer',
itemId:'placesView'
```

Why to use `itemId` over `id`?

> An itemId can be used as an alternative way to get a reference to a
>   component when no object reference is available. Instead of using an
>   id with Ext.getCmp, use itemId with Ext.Container.getComponent which
>   will retrieve itemId's or id's. **Since itemId's are an index to the
>   container's internal MixedCollection, the itemId is scoped locally to
>   the container - avoiding potential conflicts with Ext.ComponentManager
>   which requires a unique id.**

Comment: have you any example of how to use Ext.Container.getComponent with itemId? I have tried:  Ext.placesContainer.getComponent('placesView').push({                    And got this warning: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getComponent' of undefined

Comment: To retireve `itemId` you need to use [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery). For example: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#placesView')[0]`

Comment: So this is what i done @user1479606:                                               var detail=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#placesView')[0];
                console.log(detail);
                detail.push({
      xtype: 'details',
       title: name
      });
 It works perfect first time around but second time around it starts to increment the array at detail rather than push through the new screen